# Where can I see in C# that a media item is versionable?

Tags: media-library

I need to know if a uploaded media item is versionable uploaded or not? But I can't find a property on the Imagefield or MediaItem itself where I can see if the media item was uploaded versionable.

```
 var imageField = (ImageField)item.Fields[imageFieldId];
 imageField.MediaItem. ?
```

Comment: Maybe this will work: `var imageField = (ImageField)item.Fields[imageFieldId]; var isMediaItemShared = MainUtil.GetBool(imageField.MediaItem.Fields["Blob"].InnerItem["Shared"], false);`

Comment: @MarekMusielak No its not returning the right value if shared

Comment: I've tested it and it does work for me. I uploaded one image as versioned and another as not versioned and it does show correct values for both.

Comment: Meh. `versioned = imageField.MediaItem.Template.Parent.Name.Equals("Versioned");`  And I don't care if it's illogical; Sitecore has all fields marked "Shared" in the Unversioned folder - as opposed to... Unversioned ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does not look like an elegant solution but this might work. There are Versioned and Unversioned template folders under `/sitecore/templates/System/Media` path. You may try to look if your media item *template* belongs to one of these folders, smth like this:

```
if (imageField.MediaItem.Template.InnerItem.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith(
    "/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned"))
{
    // versioned
}
...
```

Comment: That was going to be my recommendation - although I would say use the Template ID's vs the path.

Comment: Might be a bit tricky since each folder contains 12 templates OOTB... But in case one does not need to deal with 'Flash', 'MP3' and other strange stuff, template IDs can be preferable.

Comment: Stop it with the ID over path nonsense :joy:

Comment: You can check if the template inherits from `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File`, all the versioned templates inherit from this one.